# Shell script: Copy file and folder N times

Tags: bash

I've two documents:

1. an .json
2. an  folder with random content

where `<transaction>` is `id+sequancial` (`id1`, `id2`... `idn`)

I'd like to populate this structure (.json +  folder) to n. I mean:

I'd like to have `id1.json` and `id1` folder, an `id2.json` and `id2` folder... `idn.json` and `idn` folder.

Is there anyway (shell script) to populate this content?

It would be something like:

```
for (i=0,i<n,i++) {
    copy "id" file to "id+i" file
    copy "id" folder to "id+i" folder
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your shell syntax is off but after that, this should be trivial.

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=0;i<$1;i++)); do
  cp "id".json "id$i".json
  cp -r "id" "id$i"
done
```

This expects the value of *n* as the sole argument to the script (which is visible inside the script in `$1`).

The C-style `for((...))` loop is Bash only, and will not work with `sh`.

A proper production script would also check that it received the expected parameter in the expected format (a single positive number) but you will probably want to tackle such complications when you learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly, here is a version working with `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

test -e id.json || { (>&2 echo "id.json not found") ; exit 1 ; }

{
    seq 1 "$1" 2> /dev/null ||
    (>&2 echo "usage: $0 transaction-count") && exit 1
} |
    while read i
    do
        cp "id".json "id$i".json
        cp -r "id" "id$i"
    done
```